# Django 3, model textField returns byte string while saved a string

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-3.2

I have updated my Django version from Django 2.1.4 to Django 3.2.3

Now I am facing a weird behavior of my apps. I am saving string data in my textFiled of the model, but when I retrieve data from model it returns byte string which is not serializable in JSON.
I have verified saved data in DB is string type.

For now, I have overridden Django model method **from_db** and checking the data type and changing it. But I think this is not a good solution.

using AWS MySQL aurora db, Django 3.2.3 and python 3.6

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Were you using the same Python version or did just Django version

Comment: python version is old not upgraded. django version is updated.